# XML "required" and "type"

Tags: xml, types, requiredfieldvalidator

I am not a professional, but I have learned a bit of HTML, so coding isn't *totally* foreign to me. I work with some technology that requires XML to add user-facing prompts when they perform an action.

I have been provided with some templates that coworkers use (none of us are programmers) and all of the templates I have been provided simply display a text box that the user types in. Looking at the code below, I have a couple of questions...

1. If I change *required="false"* to *"true"*, will it prevent the user from submitting with a blank response?
2. Are there other options I can use instead of *"textarea"* Such as a Yes/No or a numeric response?

---

```
<Inspection prompt="Some Location" name="DE">
    <Page name="Door" prompt="">
        <Group name="T1" prompt="">
            <Element type="textarea" name="Comments1" prompt="What is your name?" required="false" maxlength="500" minlength="0" />
            <Element type="textarea" name="Comments2" prompt="Is this a question?" required="false" maxlength="500" minlength="0" />
            </Group>
    </Page>
</Inspection>
```

Comment: Although XML is used in programming, and this is a programming site, your question is off-topic here because it's the application that uses this XML, not XML itself, which would determine the answers to your questions. We do not know that application and so cannot answer your questions. You'll have to direct your questions to the developers (or documentation) of the application at your company.

Answer (score 0):

XML is a syntax that defines what elements (e.g. "Inspection") and attributes (e.g. "prompt") look like, but it doesn't define what they actually mean; that's a matter for agreement between sender and recipient. There's often some kind of schema that defines what elements and attributes are allowed, but defining what they mean is typically written down in application documentation.

You say you work with "some technology that requires XML...": the answer to your question will be found in the documentation of that technology.

Without this documentation, none of us can tell you what the effect will be of changing the value of the "required" or "type" attributes.